# How are the fields delimited in a Serialized byte stram?

Tags: serialization, stream, byte

I was wondering how were delimited the fields of a serialized object in a byte stream?

Is there some kind of binary flag separating them, or are the length of each field defined at the beginning (or is it using another delimitation technique I didn't think of)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serialization is process of converting nested data (object) to flat stream. There are a lot of ways to do that. Each of them have corresponding specifications. If you want to have details tell which serialization you are interested in and lets search for docs.

Comment: In my mind I was thinking of Java serialization to store objects in files, or to send them other the network.

Comment: @nbarraille we are unable to read you mind. you didn't mention it anywhere. for java read the specification: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html everything is explained there